# Check if NavigationItem.title is equal to @"part"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sdk

```
NSString *part = self.navigationItem.title;
    if (part == @"Case") {
        NSLog(@"title: %@", part);
    }
```

and it does not log the title but if I:

```
NSLog(@"title: %@", part);
```

I get:

```
title: Case
```

Is this my error? I'm definite there's no spaces.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for compairing strings you have to use `isEqualToString`

```
if ([part isEqualToString:@"Case"]) {
    NSLog(@"title: %@", part);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't compare strings like that.

```
isEqualToString:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if([part isEqualToString:@"Case"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `==` on Obj-C objects only compares pointers. This holds true for any obj-c object. The standard way to compare obj-c objects is with `-isEqual:`, as in

```
if ([oneObj isEqual:anotherObj]) ...
```

In the case of strings there's a specialized version called `-isEqualToString:`, so you can say

```
if ([part isEqualToString:@"Case"]) ...
```

The specialized function is mostly just provided for better type-checking, since the argument must be an `NSString*` whereas `-isEqual:` allows any `id`. Aside from that, it will also be very slightly more performant than the general `-isEqual:` case, but that almost never matters.

Some other classes also have specialized comparison functions like `-[NSData isEqualToData:]`, `-[NSArray isEqualToArray:]`, and a slew of others.